# undenfined index, syntaxerror.json.parse

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the code below results me an error `Undefined index: id`   and results in a bigger error in the whole code `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` any ideas where i went wrong? It may seem a stupid question but I'm new to programming and there's so much things to know, so it's a bit hard to hang on at the start :)

```
 protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
            $q1 = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM masinos";
            $res = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

            $max_id = $row["id"];
            $max_id_plus = $max_id + 1;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO files (`carID`,`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)
                VALUES($max_id_plus,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

Comment: where is the JSON code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are asking for id while you dont have id in your select. you should give alias id.

change this

```
   $q1 = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM masinos";
```

to

```
  $q1 = "SELECT MAX(id) id FROM masinos";
```